# How to send multiple emails with a specific file for each email?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to send about 400 emails with 400 different files, I have a list with the email addresses and another with the name of the files, i created the python script in the same folder.

The mails are in a excel file.

so for example I have

mail 1
mail 2
mail 3
mail 4

and in the folder the order of the files is
file 1
file 2
file 3
file 4
so its in order.

I have this code to send 1 mail, but since i need to do this plenty of times I need to make a loop that works.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr = "YOUR EMAIL"
toaddr = "EMAIL ADDRESS YOU SEND TO"

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT OF THE EMAIL"

body = "TEXT YOU WANT TO SEND"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "NAME OF THE FILE WITH ITS EXTENSION"
attachment = open("PATH OF THE FILE", "rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "YOUR PASSWORD")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean the files are "in order"? Alphabetical, by creation timestamp, what?

Comment: Don't see any list of emails or list of filenames.

Comment: i have the list on excel in 2 columns, like MAIL - Name of file